# Multiple HTTP Requests due to img behavior tag

Tags: css, http, behavior

We have couple of portlets deployed on Websphere Portal Server. In the css file we have included a behavior attribute for img tag.

```
img {
    position:relative;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    behavior: expression((this.runtimeStyle.behavior="none")&&(this.pngSet?this.pngSet=true:(this.nodeName == "IMG" && this.src.toLowerCase().indexOf('.png')>-1?(this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none", this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.src + "', sizingMethod='image')", this.src = "transparent.gif"):(this.origBg = this.origBg? this.origBg :this.currentStyle.backgroundImage.toString().replace('url("', '').replace('")', ''), this.runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + this.origBg + "', sizingMethod='crop')", this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none")), this.pngSet=true) );
}
```

We have figured out that this behavior tag is resulting in multiple HTTP requests.In one of the Portlet JSP, we have included a style class as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style"
    href=''<%=request.getContextPath()+"/theme/stylesheet.css" %>'>
```

The issue is there only when we have that request.getContextPath(). If I substitute that with the actual context root, it is not giving the problem. Can someone please let me know why that behavior attribute is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo! has an article with the title *Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site*. One thing that is to be avoided is expressions in CSS as they are evaluated a bit more often than expected, just by moving the mouse or scrolling the page.

The article can be read here and look for the heading *Avoid CSS Expressions*:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html